Need help to decipher this Chinese calligraphy

Need help to decipher this painting Chinese calligraphy please.

From right top-down towards left -  山高水長戊辰年寫於花城XXX...

follow r13 : 從右自上而下向左 - 山高水長戊辰年寫於花城 (市?來??) 峰 百丈樓  (主?煮??)濃作
